# MySQL Insert query does not insert, but does not throw exception

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, pymysql

I have an issue where a python implemented sql query executes without raising any error but does not actually insert into db. I've tried reviewing other similar errors reported on SO but without any solution.

This is the python script connecting to db through pymysql:

```
def update_saturated_content(content_selection):
    conn = open_connection()
    conn.autocommit(True)
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        for content in content_selection:
            text = [content[0]["text"]]
            row = tuple([content[0]["list"], content[0]["link"], content[0]["promo"], content[1], float(0.2),
                         datetime.strptime(datetime.now().isoformat(), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'), 1], )
            insert_query = ('''INSERT INTO creative_tester (''' +
                            '''list, ''' +
                            '''link, ''' +
                            '''promo, ''' +
                            '''text, ''' +
                            '''weighting, ''' +
                            '''date_added, ''' +
                            '''in_use) ''' +
                            '''VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s); ''')
            cursor.execute = (insert_query, row)
            conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        return
```

Here is a sample input for the row variable above:

```
row = ('My list', 'https://mylink.com', 'My promo', "My really really really long text", 0.2, datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 7, 8, 4, 53, 429153), 1)
```

When I run the code, it completes successfully but the table does not update. If I run the exact same query via console/workebench in Google Cloud Platform, the query completes successfully and inserts the row correctly.

The cursor object during debugging shows `rowcount = -1`.

I've tried re-implementing with row as a dict, also no luck. This is the result of SHOW CREATE TABLE creative_tester;

```
| Table           | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

| creative_tester | CREATE TABLE `creative_tester` (
  `list` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `link` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `promo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` varchar(1027) DEFAULT NULL,
  `weighting` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `in_use` tinyint DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 |
```

I've tried many, many variations of trying to ensure the query string is written correctly, reformatting the datetime, using tuples vs using dictionaries, including the autocommit option, removing it, etc., without luck. One other note -- when I connect to creative_tester table via Pycharm cloud-sql-proxy and try to remove a row from this table, I get this error;

```
Unexpected update count received (Actual: 0, Expected: 1). All changes will be rolled back. com.intellij.database.console.JdbcEngineUtils$UnsafeUpdateRolledBackException: Unexpected update count received (Actual: 0, Expected: 1). All changes will be rolled back. in JdbcEngine$UpdateOperation$UnexpectedUpdatesGuard.reportChangesWillBeRolledBack(JdbcEngine.java:1927)
```

If instead, I go to the workbench and query TRUNCATE TABLE creative_tester; then the table will clear.

Appreciate any help.

EDIT 1:

```
def open_connection():
    unix_socket = '/cloudsql/{}'.format(db_connection_name)
    try:
        if os.environ.get('FLASK_ENV') == 'development':
            conn = pymysql.connect(user=db_user, password=db_password, host="127.0.0.1", port=3306, db=db_name,
                                   cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        elif os.environ.get('GAE_ENV') == 'standard':
            conn = pymysql.connect(user=db_user, password=db_password, unix_socket=unix_socket, db=db_name,
                                   cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    except pymysql.MySQLError as e:
        print(e)

    return conn
```

EDIT 2 (final code):

```
def update_saturated_content(content_selection):
    conn = open_connection()
    conn.begin()
    conn.autocommit(True)
    creative_update = []
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        for content in content_selection:
            text = [content[0]["text"]]
            creative_update.append(tuple([content[0]["list"], content[0]["link"], content[0]["promo"], content[1], float(0.2),
                         datetime.now().isoformat(), 1], ))
            query = ('UPDATE creative_tester '
                     'SET in_use = 0 WHERE text LIKE (%s) '
                     'AND in_use = 1; ')
            cursor.execute(query, tuple(text, ))
        insert_query = ('INSERT INTO creative_tester ('
                        'list, '
                        'link, '
                        'promo, '
                        'text, '
                        'weighting, '
                        'date_added, '
                        'in_use) '
                        'VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)')
        cursor.executemany(insert_query, creative_update)
        conn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        return
```

Comment: Before I try plough through that text, please note that `'''` starts a block quote so you can get rid of the `'''` and the `+` at the end of `'''INSERT INTO creative_tester (''' +` and just make a single string. Everything inside the block quotes will automatically be "concatenated" across lines so you don't need to open and close them on every single line

Comment: And the insert_query doesn't need the brackqtes, so you can do **insert_query = '''INSERT INTO...**

Comment: That said, there is nothing wrong with the code you have shown that would explain this that I can see. The only things I can think of are a) `conn = open_connection()` does not connect to what you think it does or b) `content_selection` is actually empty by the time it gets to your function

Comment: Added in the open_connection script -- I can confirm that the credentials work as expected and that content_selection is not empty during debugging. Likewise, for all other queries in the same project open_connection() authenticates correctly and INSERT queries in other functions work as expected.

Comment: When you say that the table does not update, how are you verifying this? Bear in mind that, depending on isolation level, other connections may need to commit before they can see rows committed by other transactions.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I'm verifying just by querying the table after the initial script finishes. I'm not a SQL expert, so I'm not super familiar with what you mean by other transactions/connections -- I can say that I've set up this table "creative_tester" as an "isolated" (in normal vernacular, not sure if you're using "isolation level" with a specific meaning) table with no keys/indexes because I was experiencing the exact same issue in my production table.

Comment: 1) Why are you using this `cursor.execute = (insert_query, row)` instead of a normal method call `cursor.execute(insert_query, row)`? 2) You are using `autocommit(True)` and `conn.commit()` but no `conn.begin()`. 3) I recommend changing your logic to commit all inserts as one transaction instead of a transaction per insert. That will dramatically improve performance. Is there a reason for committing one transaction per insert? If not, then commit all inserts as one transaction or at least group them into batches of X number per commit.

Comment: If I count your tuple row, it’s 8 values, but your table has only 7 columns, right?

Comment: @JohnHanley your suggestions solved the issue. I'm not positive whether it was the conn.begin() command or that I had erroneously bungled the method call (this seems to be a situation where one stares at something so long they can no longer see it), but having resolved both of those issues the query is now working. Thanks!

Comment: Both were problems breaking your code.

Comment: @planck_spaceFWIW I was referring to [this concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)), but it sounds like you have resolved your issue now.